# Use a contextual filter value in a view referencing a node name/path rather than id

Tags: 7, uri, views

I would like to create a views that has a contextual filter with a node reference.

I'm able to view the contextual filter working when I use the node's id value, but I need to be able to use the alias or name value of that content type. I have people categorized by office (the office is also a content type because it has much more content than a taxonomy would allow). Then using the office location as a contextual filter I'm trying to show the "team" listed for each office.

/office/atlanta/team rather than /office/6/team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Term: ID you might want to use Term: Name. I believe you can also check a box in the contextual filter options panel to display "Term ID converted to term name".

Comment: I think the problem for the OP is that the filter is not a taxonomy term but a node reference so the options you specify are not available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it could be something like

> [term:vocabulary]/[term:name]

Comment: You mean in the path for that view I'd use
`about-us/market-offices/[term:name]/team`
rather than 
`about-us/market-offices/%/team`